# Internal server error with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Trying to make this ajax call work.But I get the 500 Internal server error.

Updated: Script.js

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '/books/103/last_chapter.json',
  success: function(data) {
    $("body").append(data);
  },  
error: function(xhr, status, response) {console.log('response ' + response +  ' ,  xhr' + xhr +  ' ,  ' + 'STATUS ' + status)}
});
```

Chapter controller:

```
def last_chapter
    Chapter.order(created_at: :desc).limit(1)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js 
    end
end
```

config.routes

```
resources :books do 
    member do 
      get '/last_chapter/', to: 'chapters#last_chapter', as: 'last_chapter'
    end
    resources :chapters
end
```

How the route looks in the terminal:

```
 last_chapter_book GET         /books/:id/last_chapter(.:format)chapters#last_chapter
```

The error in terminal

```
Started GET "/books/103/last_chapter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-12 14:17:37 +0200
Processing by ChaptersController#last_chapter as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"103"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template chapters/last_chapter, application/last_chapter with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/namek/myrails/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/chapters_controller.rb:28:in `last_chapter'
```

last_chapter.json

```
json.extract! @last_chapter, :id, :title, :characters, :created_at, :updated_at
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `last_chapter.json` in `views/chapters/last_chapter` with the JSON you want to return.

Comment: Thanks! That removed the error, but nothing being appended to the body. I tried adding a console.log() in the ajax but that did not print either.  

I made the last_chapter.js and wrote this:
json.extract! @chapter, :id, :title, :created_at, :updated_at

Comment: You need to define `@chapter` in your controller: `@chapter = Chapter.order(created_at: :desc).limit(1)`

Comment: Still gets nothing :/

Comment: Edited my answer, the file extension should be `.json`, not `.js`

Comment: Now I get the error again. And I also tried changing the
respond_to do |format|
        format.js 
    end 

to 
respond_to do |format|
        format.json
    end

Comment: You need to add `.json` when calling the resource when making your ajax call: `url: '/books/103/last_chapter.json',`

Comment: So sorry, to be bothering you like this, so thank you for sticking by. It still does not work :/

Comment: No worries :). Try to add a `binding.pry` (pry gem) in your view to see if it gets called. If it does, try to display the value of @chapter.

Comment: Thanks again! :) How and in what file do I put the binding.pry ? (in booklist.html.erb? )

Comment: In `last_chapter.json`. This is what you're actually trying to render.

Comment: aha! Nothing happend. but I did add an "error" part to my ajax. This is what it prints out: 
response SyntaxError: Unexpected token j , 
xhr[object Object] ,  
STATUS parsererror

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add your `last_chapter.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 get '/last_chapter/', to: 'chapters#last_chapter', as: 'last_chapter', defaults: { format: 'js' }
   and create a file in its view last_chapter.js.erb
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to the Ajax request => `content-type: "application/json"`

with this action:

```
def last_chapter
    @last_chapter = Chapter.order(created_at: :desc).limit(1)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @last_chapter }
    end
end
```

Comment: Didn't work :/ Everything went white and I got this error in the console:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://kchdfagjljmhgapoonapmfngpadcjkhk/js/scripts.js:24:42)
    at chrome-extension://kchdfagjljmhgapoonapmfngpadcjkhk/js/scripts.js:11:21

Comment: sorry is contentType, no content-type in the ajax request :) and add dataType: "json" too.

Comment: Thanks alot for helping! but still gets the same error message :(